# trigger function when ODBC connection is opend in Ms Access

Tags: ms-access

In the init phase of my ms access app, I set some links to ODBC tables in a postgresql db. I also set the application name with a statement "set application_name = ... ;".

So far it works well, but ...

After a phase of inactivity (or some other reason) the connection is closed. After accessing a linked table, the connection is reopen automatically. That is pretty cool, but ...

=> the application_name is lost.

Question: Can I use a trigger function, when ms access is opening a new connection or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just using linked tables, then no, unfortunately, this is not possible.

Access manages the connection internally for tables, and doesn't fire any events when reconnecting.

If you're only using forms, you can manage the connection yourself using a predeclared self-healing object. In that case you can raise events when reconnecting, and let the object set the application name.

Another half-solution is to use passthrough queries instead of tables, and start them all off with `set application_name`

Comment: My best solution so far, is working with a timer. The connection can stay with the default timeout. ... I have not tested it in production.

Comment: That's a _works 99% of the time_ solution: in between the timer interval, the connection might expire. If you depend on application_name being set, it won't be 100% stable.